# Pytest report not capturing the output for each test case

Tags: pytest

Hi I have following code snippet that I have defined for generating html report using pytest:

```
# define a hook to add the environment info to the HTML Report
def pytest_configure (config):
    config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'Networks'
    config._metadata['Module Name'] = 'Networks Automation'
    config._metadata['Tester'] = 'Greg Williams'




 # define a hook to delete/modify the environment info in the HTML Report
   @pytest.hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
   def pytest_metadata(metadata):
       metadata.pop("JAVA_HOME", None)
       metadata.pop("Plugins", None)
```

From my PyCharm terminal I am using the following command:

```
pytest -s -v --html=Reports/report.html testCases/test_login.py --browser chrome
```

My test cases run and pass and the report.html gets generated. However, the report says 'No log output captured.' under each test case reported. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.[image]

Comment: The `-s` flag disables capturing any output. Replace with `--capture=tee-sys` instead to see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the -s to capture the stdout instead of display it.

The `pytest -s` command is used to run tests using the pytest framework while displaying the standard output (stdout) from the test functions. The -s option stands for "capture no-stdout" and is used to disable the default capturing of stdout by pytest.

By default, pytest captures the stdout output from test functions and displays it only if the test fails. This behavior is useful for keeping the test output clean and focused on failures. However, in some cases, you may want to see the stdout output even when the tests pass, which is where the -s option comes in.